# Broken DAG: No module named 'airflow.contrib.gsc_to_gcs'

Tags: python, docker, airflow

Very new to Airflow/Python etc. but can't seem to work out what I need to do to resolve this issue..

Airflow is running on Puckel/Docker

Full error is:

```
Broken DAG : [/usr/local/airflow/dags/xxxx.py] No module named 'airflow.contrib.operators.gsc_to_gcs'
```

In the python code, I've written:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gcs import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
```

I'm guessing I need to install the `gcs_to_gcs` module, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any specific instructions would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: What version of airflow does the docker image use? It could be that the `gcs_to_gcs` operator does not yet exist in the version of airflow that the puckel docker image is using.

Answer (score 7):

The `GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` wasn't available in v1.9.0 so you will have to copy the file from [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py) and the related hook from [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py) and paste it in the Airflow folder in your python environment at the respective location. Follow the steps below:

Run the following code to find where Apache Airflow is stored on your machine:

```
pip show apache-airflow
```

which should produce the following output on your terminal:

```
Name: apache-airflow
Version: 2.0.0.dev0+incubating
Summary: Programmatically author, schedule and monitor data pipelines
Home-page: http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/
Author: Apache Software Foundation
Author-email: dev@airflow.incubator.apache.org
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /Users/kaxil/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: iso8601, bleach, gunicorn, sqlalchemy-utc, markdown, flask-caching, alembic, croniter, flask-wtf, requests, tabulate, psutil, jinja2, gitpython, python-nvd3, sqlalchemy, dill, flask, pandas, pendulum, flask-login, funcsigs, flask-swagger, flask-admin, lxml, python-dateutil, pygments, werkzeug, tzlocal, python-daemon, setproctitle, zope.deprecation, flask-appbuilder, future, configparser, thrift
Required-by:
```

The path after **Location:** is your **Apache Airflow** directory

Now clone the git repo to get those two files:

```
# Clone the git repo to `airflow-temp` folder
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow airflow-temp

# Copy the hook from the cloned repo to where Apache Airflow is located
# Replace LINK_TO_SITE_PACKAGES_DIR with the path you found above
cp airflow-temp/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py LINK_TO_SITE_PACKAGES_DIR/airflow/contrib/hooks/

# For example: for me, it would be 
cp airflow-temp/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py /Users/kaxil/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/

# Do the same with operator file
cp airflow-temp/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py LINK_TO_SITE_PACKAGES_DIR/airflow/contrib/operators/

# For example: for me, it would be 
cp airflow-temp/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py /Users/kaxil/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/
```

Re-run the Airflow `webserver` and `scheduler` and this should now work.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me with very detailed, accurate and understand instructions.

This gave me exactly what I needed, thanks!

I couldn't run 'pip show apache-airflow' because pip wasn't installed on my machine. Once installed, 'pip show apache-airflow' returned nothing for me.

Instead, I searched all folders for "site-packages", found a few folders that matched the criteria and copied the hook and operator like you said.

I didn't know how to re-run the Airflow web server & scheduler but my DAG worked anyway.

Thank you!!

Comment: @MattLaz Glad that it helped you somewhat if not entirely and now it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here, helped me a lot.

Side question, how do you tell what is available in each release of airflow?

Comment: @VendableFall release notes

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just tried to use this same operator and received the same message since Cloud-Composer is still not supporting `GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`.

I managed to achieve what I needed with a workaround using a simple BashOperator

```
    from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

with models.DAG(
            dag_name,
            schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
            default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

        copy_files = BashOperator(
            task_id='copy_files',
            bash_command='gsutil -m cp <Source Bucket> <Destination Bucket>'
        )
```

Is very straightforward, can create folders if you need and rename your files.

Comment: You can update the cloud composer, airflow version 1.10.0 is available https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions?hl=uk